# sass mixins and css custom properties

Tags: css, sass

aye folks!

i tried to build a sass mixin for css custom properties to make work a little bit easier.

my attempt does look like this:

```
@mixin mixin($value) {
  background: unquote('$')#{$value};
  background: var(--#{$value}, unquote('$')#{$value});
}
```

the output looks like this:

```
.example {
  background: $value;
  background: var(--colour, $value);
}
```

BUT sass doesn't convert my $value into the actual thing. the $value part end up in my final css file and ofc this doesn't work.

i tried to find a solution online but i'm either to dumb to find it or there isn't one. anyone here has an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the CSS output you expect?

Comment: something like `background: $abcdef;` but what i get is `background: $value;` because sass doesn't seem to convert the variable into it's given value.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, with your code if you pass `#abcdef` in the `$value` variable you get  `#abcdef`, and why are you using interpolation?

Comment: exactly this is what isn't happening. i don't get #abcdef. it just spits out the variable like $value in my css.
and i'm using interpolation because otherwise i'll get spaces in the css aswell. (like `background: var(-- value, $ value);`)

Answer (score 0):

I have try your code with this example:

```
@mixin mixin($value) {
  background: unquote('$')#{$value};
  background: var(--#{$value}, unquote('$')#{$value});
}

.example {
  @include mixin(colour)
}
```

and it works.
The output is:

```
.example {
  background: $colour;
  background: var(--colour, $colour);
}
```

is what you want? Sorry but I don't have the authorization for add comment so I create this answer.

Edit: you can create a different mixin like this:

```
@mixin mixin($value, $color) {
      background: $color;
      background: var(--#{$value}, $color);
    }
```

This help you to solve your problem?

Comment: the problem ist that it doesn't replace the variables with the actual colour in my css output. i just get `background: $colour;` instead of `background: #abcdef;`

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. Days ago I have the same problem but I discovered that Sass does not allow variables to be created or accessed dynamically.

Comment: wich means, if i got that right, that there is no way to build a mixin like that? meh.. alrighty then. thanks anyways! (:

Comment: I'm using the mixin for don't repeat the same blocks of code in the scss files or if the block of code depends of some input field. I hope that I have been useful to you :)